# WordPress : Cant change link for navigation item

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm customizing a WordPress theme so problem is that I've to change a link. its in Arabic for example instead of this i want to make it like this but problem is that i don't find link for the item see attached image

[image]

now how do i change its link please help.for some of  the other links  i can  change but not this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change it because it is a page. You can remove it if you don't want it in the menu, and add another page instead or you can add a custom link, for which you can specify the Navigation label and the url.

Comment: how do i add custom link ? please let me know this .

Comment: You can see it in the left side of the screen, when you edit a menu. There are tabs for adding posts, pages, categoryes, custom links, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot  .. i just added a custom link